# How to pass xml string from .cs file to javascript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am creating a website for **Online Shopping**. So, I want to make multi column dynamic menu bar. Categories and Subcategories are will be displayed as a menu items. I have created a function to get records from database and generate xml file based on hierarchy relationship of categories in .cs file. Now, I wan to post that xml file to javascript function. So, can do further process to generate dynamic menu. But, i dont know how to that? Is there any other way to do same thing. I want to read that xml file and create menu items. I am new in Web Application Developing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an asp.net `HiddenField` control. Assign the xml string to the control using C# and access the control's value on client side using `js`.

Comment: You might want to encode your xml string though. Or at least escape the double quotes in your xml string. Otherwise you might get alot of "unterminated string constant" errors